# Passing a pointer of a list to a function

Tags: function, pointers

So I am relearning programming. I learned Pascal back in the 1980s. So I am a newbie.
I have a class that has several different int,floats and strings.
I want to pass the pointer to this class to a function.
How do I pass it from Main to the function?
Once in the function, how do I access the information in the list?

Thanks
Glenn

Comment: What language are you talking about? And are you talking about a class or a list? What have you done so far? Your question is far too vague to be answered.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.